# Restsharp API authentication request

Tags: c#, restsharp

I am trying to post the following JSON with RestSharp:

```
{ "username": "test_user", "password": "super$3kretp4ssword" }
```

so this is the c# code i wrote

```
var client = new RestClient("https://accept.paymobsolutions.com/api/auth/tokens");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
request.AddParameter("application/json", request.AddJsonBody(new { username = "myUsername", password = "myPassword" }), ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

But on debugging the `response.content` is `""`

The response should be:

```
{
  "token": "ZXlKaGlPaUpJVXpVeE1pSX1Y0NJmV5Sn...", // this is your authentication token
  "profile": {
    "id": 28, // this is your merchant_id
    "user": {
      "id": 31,
      "username": "test_user",
      "first_name": "test_user",
      "last_name": "test_user",
    },
    "created_at": "2016-11-20T16:27:20.067296Z",

    ...
  }
}
```

[image: Debugging Result Here]

Comment: What are the other fields of the `response` variable?

Comment: @Progman please see the edit

Comment: No, what are the other fields of your `response` variable? Specially the `StatusCode` field.

Comment: response.StatusCode = 0

Comment: What are **all** the fields from the `response` variable? Please edit the question to include all the fields and the values they have from the `response` variable. They might contain information why the request failed. In your case, it looks like it wasn't even send to the server.

Comment: @Progman please refer to the screenshot, thank you for your patience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exception is related to `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol`

For .NET 4 use the following to solve the problem

`ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)768 | (SecurityProtocolType)3072;`

Answer (score 0):

Sending th request failed because "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred ...". Check the `ErrorException` field to see the reason why your request failed.